# error in viewcontroller (lldb) when presenting another view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uiactivityviewcontroller

when I try to present an uiactivityviewcontroller or just another viewcontroller, I get an lldb error without any further explanation

EDITED:

Game starts with GameMenuScene, when play is clicked it will move to GameScene:

```
class GameMenuScene: SKScene {
weak var weakGameVC: GameViewController?
            if nodeAtPoint.name == "play"{
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score+1, forKey: "currentLevel")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                self.removeAllActions()
                self.removeAllChildren()
                var scene1:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                scene1.weakGameVC = self                           @@Updated : error: SKSCene does not have a member named "weakGameVC"
                self.view?.presentScene(scene1)
            }
}
```

GameScene:

Here is the GameViewController(as you can see, first scene is GameMenuScene:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import Social


class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

weak var weakGameVC: GameViewController?      @@Updated
var player:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var scene:GameMenuScene!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameMenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.weakGameVC = self                         @@Updated
    //scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}



func shareButton()  {
     var myShare = "aa"
     let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["aa"], applicationActivities: nil)
  presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

And here the GameScene, where the gameplay is:

```
import SpriteKit
import Social


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
weak var weakGameVC: GameViewController?

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location: CGPoint! = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let nodeAtPoint = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

            if (nodeAtPoint.name != nil) {
              if   nodeAtPoint.name == "share"{
               println("1")
               if let gvc = weakGameVC {
                    println("2")
                    gvc.shareButton()
                }
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: It's a breakpoint, you have to disable it or remove it.

Comment: nope, I deactivated breakpoints

Comment: and when I try this on my Iphone, the app crashes too

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from Xcode after the app crash, please?

Comment: screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/tt9liw6f7/

Comment: When do you call shareButton() method?

Comment: when a spritenode is touched, see edit(2nd block of code)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because in `touchBegan` method you create new object `GameViewController`:

```
var gameViewController = GameViewController()
```

The `gameViewController` is not added to the view hierarchy (it's not presented) and after that you call `shareButton()` method which wants to present another view (share view) on not presented view (game view).

The solution should be that you handle the touch (touchesBegan) in the same class where you have `shareButton()` by calling `shareButton()` on the self not `gameViewController.shareButton()`.
Or create delegate method from scene to view controller, if touch happened in scene call delegate method and handle it in view controller to present the share view

// EXTENDED - Solution with weak reference to game view controller.

In GameScene add weak reference to gameVC:

```
weak var weakGameVC: GameViewController?
```

and later in the same file:

```
if nodeAtPoint.name == "share" {
   if let gvc = weakGameVC {
      gvc.shareButton()
   }
}
```

In GameViewController file after you create game scene you have to add something like that:

```
gameScene.weakGameVC = self
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67494/discussion-on-answer-by-greg-error-in-viewcontroller-lldb-when-presenting-anot).